# Password field (and confirmation) showing up twice on registration

Tags: user-registration, password

Before I state my problem, I'd like to explain what I've been doing. I am trying to find a membership plugin to work with my site. I only have one registration (free membership) needed. I have been playing with several plugins, including s2members, formidable registration, paid membership pro, and currently membership 2.

I've also had plugins buddy press (uninstalled) and woocommerce( currently disabled) that had inputs on registration. as well as formidable forms registration.  None of them besides formidable forms and s2member plugins, and woocommerce were run at the same time.

I simply needed something that would allow me to restrict certain content if a user was not logged in for a photography website. I need to create custom fields to collect address info and all so people can book a shoot.

Anyway, the point of this post, is that somewhere along the line, I've now got a messed up registration and I don't know how to fix it back to default so that I can simply start over, or how to repair the issue.

When a user registers, currently only the basic fields from wordpress are appearing, none of my custom meta fields. But for some reason the password field appears twice.  And I'm not talking about the verification.

It ask for a password, and verification twice in one form.

I can't figure out how to get rid of that.  The second password request also comes out with different formatting than the rest of the form which indicates that is is being pulled from somewhere else I would assume.

I really have no idea where to even start looking to determine what is causing this extra field to show up.

I really just need to reset the user meta options and start over, then find a free plugin that will allow me to add custom fields to registration, and then restrict certain pages until a user is logged in.  Any ideas how to fix this password issue would be appreciated.

Link: http://dev.unicriscreations.com/register/?step=register

I did notice though when simply logging out and clicking register on the log-in page, i get a different link registration form that doesn't have the issue, but also does not have my custom fields. 
http://dev.unicriscreations.com/login/?action=register

Comment: Sorry, but this is a very localised question and it's unlikely anyone will be able to help - that's not to say anyone won't, just don't be surprised if the tumbleweeds roll in. I will say that the the troublemaker is definitely an _activated_ plugin and/or your theme - try switching to Twenty Sixteen and disabling all plugins, then re-activate one by one to find it.